RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<CustomInterface> with string works, not with custom object
I had a custom "JobExecuter" to run http calls with a single instance HttpClient. Which worked:
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    string? cron = job.CronExpression;
    string name = job.Name;
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<JobExecuter>(name, exec => exec.Execute(job.url), cron, options);
}

public class JobExecuter
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public JobExecuter(HttpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task Execute(string url)
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}

But I want to add a Job, which will execute after a specific job is done. So I changed:
exec.Execute(job.url) to exec.Execute(job.url). Where the JobExecuter now handles the childJobs. Using BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith because in the api configuration, the created RecurringJob won't exists until it's executed first.
public async Task Execute(Job job)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(job.Url, null);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    foreach (var continuedJob in job.ContinuationJobs) 
    {
        await Execute(continuedJob);
    }
}

But when a job is started, job.Url is null. What am I missing here? It's a public Property and in every constructor, the url is set. See details below.
public class Job
{
    public string Url { get; }
    public string? CronExpression { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Job[] ContinuationJobs => continuationJobs.ToArray();
    private readonly List<Job> continuationJobs = new();

    public bool IsEmptyObject = false;
    public Job()
    {
        IsEmptyObject = true;
    }

    private Job(string url)
    {
        Url = url;
        Name = Url[(Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)..];
    }

    public Job(JobSchedule schedule, string url)
    {
        CronExpression = JobScheduleConverter.ToCron(schedule);
        Url = url;
        Name = Url[(Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)..];
    }

    public Job(JobSchedule schedule, string url, params string[] continuationJobUrls)
    {
        CronExpression = JobScheduleConverter.ToCron(schedule);
        Url = url;
        Name = Url[(Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)..];
        continuationJobs = continuationJobUrls.Select(x => new Job(x)).ToList();
    }
}

Additional details:

When opening the hangfire's dashboard, an empty Job class is initiated. I don't know why. But the job inside Execute, is not that class.

